# Чтение из кафки с фильтрацией - архитектурная ошибка?

Tags: apache-kafka

Верно ли утверждение, что читать сообщения из кафки и потом фильтровать его на основе какого-то параметра - плохая идея и это архитектурная ошибка?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт user583023, пожалуйста ознакомьтесь с сылками: ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Утверждение ложное. Это распространенная практика. Кафка это брокер сообщений, если вам нужен какой-то определенный порядок после полученния данных - то нет проблем отсортировать их

Comment: @Aarnihauta Кажется, вы путаете фильтрацию с сортировкой )

Comment: @CrazyElf упс, не заметил) Да в общем-то какая разница? Получил данные - делай с ними что хочешь и как хочешь)

Comment: @Aarnihauta Ну, от этого зависит ответ на вопрос. Если нужна сортировка, то всё нормально, можно потом отсортировать. А если фильтрация, то однозначно лучше фильтровать заранее в новый топик )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под фильтрацией вы имеете в виду отбор только части нужных вам сообщений по какому-то признаку, то в идеале под каждую цель должен быть выделен некий топик, который вы читаете целиком. Если в `Kafka` попадают какие-то данные, из которых часть нужна одним консьюмерам, а часть другим, то фильтровать данные на консьюмере - плохая идея, потому что получается, что вы зазря гоняете через `Kafka` лишние данные. Есть специальная концепция `Kafka streams`, которая предназначена как-раз для того, чтобы фильтровать данные из `Kafka` и класть обратно в неё же.

Например, у вас есть некий топик `AllData` с данными, часть из которых нужна одним консьюмерам, а часть другим. Вы пишете сервис на `Kafka streams`, который осуществляет фильтрацию и кладёт отфильтрованные данные обратно же в `Kafka`, скажем в топики `SystemData` и `ClientData`. И потом консьюмеры двух разных групп читают эти топики целиком, уже без фильтрации. Такая схема правильная.

Просто считается, что пишутся данные один раз, а читаться могут много раз по разным причинам. Один и тот же топик могут читать разные группы консьюмеров, например. Или консьюмер может периодически перестартовывать и читать заново тот же топик. Поэтому лучше сразу данные отфильтровать и положить в отдельный топик, тогда оверхед на эту фильтрацию будет минимальный - она будет произведена только один раз сразу при записи в фильтруемый вами топик, а не каждый раз при чтении из фильтруемого топика, как в примере из вашего вопроса.

Если же вы точно уверены, что данные из топика читаются строго один раз и только вами, тогда разницы где фильтровать данные, конечно, не будет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. в целом точно такой же позиции придерживался, хотел просто уточнить не один ли я такой :)

Comment: @saymynamej Так то я и сам в общем начинающий кафкианец, но стараюсь сразу глубоко копать ))  Из разговоров с админами кафки у меня в целом сложилось впечатление, что место они особо не экономят, а вот за доступность и отзывчивость сервиса бьются изо всех сил, поэтому в их парадигме лучше создать лишний топик, потратив на это некоторое место, но зато сэкономить все прочие ресурсы, повысив скорость работы таким образом.